# Many connection for get one record VS One connection for get all records in Mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a ftp server and i get list of files every 10 minutes . The ftp server usually has one millions files. The list of files must be insert in database uniquely. So i want check the file name before exist on database or not . I have two solution for this:

1- For each of file in ftp server, connect to database and check file name exist or not (Many connection)

2- First get all record(one connection) in database and store in ArrayList and for each file in ftp server check contain  file name exists in ArrayList or not.

Which solution is better? for solution 2 i concern for memory usage.
I used JDBC Driver for connect database.

Comment: Could you just query a database to check if the filename exists on it? This way you wouldn't have to copy all the records to `ArrayList` or such.

Comment: Both solutions aren't very good. You don't want to do this in Java, so you have to do it in the database itself. But use a primary key/unique constraint to disallow duplicate entries, and then modify your query in such a way that only non-existing entries are stored, as per wdc's answer.

Comment: @SeverityOne I use INSERT IGNORE FILES (name ,status) values (?,1) command and name is UNIQUE constraint . When file name is no exist, must be download from ftp server. so before insert i must be check file name exist or not and when  not exist, download file from ftp server. My problem is performance of check file name.

Comment: @wdc. List of file names from ftp server are unique (save in fileArray) and  when i get all record(save in list), i sure new insert file name does not match with any file name in current list file name(fileArray).

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure the filename doesn't exists before inserting to the database. In this way you don't need to copy anything to `List` and then checking the `List` itself. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES (val1, val2, val3)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
table.col1 = val1 and table.col2 = val2 and table.col3 = val3
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I use INSERT IGNORE FILES (name ,status) values (?,1). I want download file from ftp server when not exist in database.